# Retrieve dataextension from Triggered Send Defination

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, dataextensions, c#, send-definition

How can I retrieve information from a Data-extension along with columns from a Triggered Send Definition?

From C# application using SOAP API, we need to retrieve Data-extension associated with corresponding Triggered Send definition. Basically we need to validate columns before creating Triggered Send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the **SendSourceDataExtension** property of the [**TriggeredSendDefinition**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggeredsenddefinition.htm) object is not retrievable via SOAP API.